# Can't remove file installed by another installer

Tags: wix

I want to:

1. Create a directory.
2. Run another installer (not MSI) that installs some files into directory from point 1.
3. Replace some of the files installed at point 2.

All of these must be done under my installation created with the help of WiX (Windows Installer XML).

There is an important part of my WiX file below. The problem is this installation doesn't replace the files as I want. To remove files I use RemoveFile element with Property attribute, because it is the only way (except writing code within custom action - that is I do not want) to remove files that isn't in the installer database.

```xml
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerDirectory" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
            <Directory Id="ProductDirectory" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
                <Directory Id="SubDirectory" Name="$(var.SubDirectoryName)">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<!-- Create the directory at point 1. -->
<Component
    Id="RemoveOldData" Guid="..."   KeyPath="yes" 
    Directory="ManufacturerDirectory">
    <CreateFolder Directory="ProductDirectory" />
</Component>

<!-- Following two components replace the file(s) (point 3). -->

<Component
    Id="RemoveOldData" Guid="..."
    Directory="SubDirectory" KeyPath="yes"      
    >   
    <RemoveFile 
        Id="Remove_MyFile.exe" On="install"
        Property="SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY" Name="MyFile.exe" />
</Component>

<Component
    Id="FilesToReplace" Guid="..."
    Directory="SubDirectory">
    <File 
        Id="MyFile.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"        
        Source="$(var.SourcePath)MyFile.exe" Name="MyFile.exe"
        />
</Component>

<Binary Id="WiseInstallation" SourceFile="$(var.WiseSourcePath)..." />

<!-- Launch Wise installation at point 2. -->
<CustomAction
    Id="LaunchWiseInstallation"
    BinaryKey="WiseInstallation"
    ExeCommand=""
    Return="check"
    Execute="deferred"
    Impersonate="yes" />

<!-- Following custom action assigns a property.
This needs to remove files that are not in the current installer database.
To do it, the Property attribute of the RemoveFile element is needed. -->   
<CustomAction
    Id="Assign_SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY"
    Property="SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY"
    Value="[SubDirectory]" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Assign_SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY" After="InstallInitialize" >
        NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action="LaunchWiseInstallation" After="CreateFolders" >
        NOT Installed</Custom>
    <RemoveFiles Sequence="3720"/>
    <RemoveFolders Sequence="3730"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

InstallExecuteSequence from Orca's view:

- ValidateProductID        700
- CostInitialize       800
- FileCost     900
- CostFinalize     1000
- InstallValidate      1400
- InstallInitialize        1500
- **Assign_SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY        1501**
- ProcessComponents        1600
- UnpublishFeatures        1800
- RemoveRegistryValues     2600
- RemoveShortcuts      3200
- CreateFolders        3700
- **LaunchWiseInstallation   3701**
- **RemoveFiles        3720**
- **RemoveFolders      3730**
- InstallFiles     4000
- CreateShortcuts      4500
- WriteRegistryValues      5000
- RegisterUser     6000
- RegisterProduct      6100
- PublishFeatures      6300
- PublishProduct       6400
- InstallFinalize      6600

I also checked install log file:

- the SUBDIRECTORYPROPERTY property was assigned well;
- the InstallExecuteSequence was followed properly;
- installation was completed without errors.

BUT THE FILES WASN'T EVER REMOVED OR REPLACED!

Answer (score 1):

First, an MSI cannot install another MSI so the installation package in #2 cannot be an MSI. If it is not, then schedule the custom action that launches the other installation package like so:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='LaunchOtherInstaller' After='CreateFolders' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The `CreateFolders` action happens before the `InstallFiles` action so your installer should be able to jump in between.

Comment: Sorry, Rob, but I think you misunderstood me a little. I explored the question and found solution by myself. I posted an answer about it. Can you check me, please - am I right in details or not?

Comment: I don't see any mention in your question about having to delete arbitrary files from disk. Your answer is not correct, I left a comment pointing out that `RemoveFile` element would work if you just want a bunch of files deleted. You might try clarifying the question a bit to get better answers.

Comment: I changed my question for clarity. I also remove coded custom action and use just RemoveFile element. To do it with arbitrary files (and files installed by another installer is the case) I should use the Property attribute of the RemoveFile element, and I should assign this property with according directory of the file to be removed, if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I realized that MSI can't directly delete the files installed by another installer (MSI or not) - it works only with files mentioned within its database at installation process (i.e. the files installed by itself or by previous version of itself). But with custom action it can. So the point 3 can't be achieved without custom action. So the right sequence can be like this:

```xml
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom 
    Action="LaunchWiseInstallation" 
    After="CreateFolders" 
    >
    NOT Installed
    </Custom>
  <Custom 
    Action="DeleteOldData" 
    After="LaunchWiseInstallation" 
    >
    NOT Installed
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

where DeleteOldData is a CustomAction element that points to the DLL or .exe that contains the custom action that actually deletes the files. It only can be mentioned that perhaps  DeleteOldData custom action should have Execute="deferred" attribute to run in-script, and should have Impersonate="yes" attribute to avoid UAC restrictions and files access. The latter is true if the installer is running by the user with administrative privileges which is higher than LocalSystem's preveleges.

And the RemoveFile tag can only work with files mentioned within MSI's database - not with random files. So it is useless in this situation.

Comment: The `RemoveFile` element can remove files from anywhere on disk. A custom action shouldn't be necessary here.